# Maven modules and dependencies - functional test a library

Tags: java, maven, module, dependencies, functional-testing

The ultimate goal is to find out a way to functional test a library.

I have a parent project A with sub modules B,C and D.

Let us assume that the module C has a dependency on module B (B being the library) and is included as a maven dependency using the `<dependency>` tag.

I am just curious to know when I start up the application server say Tomcat would a jar for B (along with others) be created and then C uses this jar?

I tried to monitor my directories to see whether jars were being created every time the server was started up but that doesn't seem to be the case.

If B isn't used as a jar then it would not exactly be a FT since the ultimate goal is to be able to use B as a library in other projects as well. I feel like this shouldn't be a problem since the code itself does not change but I'd like to get some insight into the same and comments if any. Thank you !

Comment: If all you want to do it make a reproducable test system, you might want to look at JUnit and Mockito.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I get it right, because you seem to mix building, deploying and testing

- Maven will only build the current pom. It will not build dependency libraries but expect to find them in the repository.
- Only if module A is a multi-module build, then B, C and D will be built when you build A.
- Starting a tomcat will not trigger any build.

For a functional test you would build, package and deploy and execute your tests against the full application.